# Bounding double sum off diagonal

Tags: inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I have to prove the following bound
$$
\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{\substack{m\leq N\\ m\neq n}}|a_ma_n|\left(\log\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\leq\sum_{n\leq N}|a_n|^2\sum_{1\leq m <n}\left(\frac{m}{n-m}\right)^2
$$
I think I have to use the fact that $1-\frac{1}{x}\leq \log x$ to get
$$
\left(\log \frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\leq\left(\frac{m}{n-m}\right)^2
$$
but then I don't know how to reduce the term off the diagonal to a sum only of the diagonal terms. Any advice is welcome, thank you!

**Edit.** The above inequality is not true for $N=2$ as pointed out by Doyun Nam. What I eventually wanted to show is the following bound
$$
\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{\substack{m\leq N\\ m\neq n}}|a_ma_n|\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\ll \sum_{n\leq N}n^2|a_n|^2
$$
Maybe is easier to directly prove such bound without pasing first through the first inequality that I have written (which turned out to be wrong).

Comment: I'm not sure your inequality is true. I checked in the case $N=2$. And I think at that time, this inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: which $\{a_n\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ have you considered?

Comment: When $N=2$, I get the inequality 

$$|a_2 a_1|(\log2)^{-2} + |a_1 a_2| (\log\frac{1}{2})^{-2} \leq |a_2|^2 .$$ And If $|a_1|$ goes to infinity, then the left-hand side goes to infinity.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. Would $\sum_{m\neq n}$ on the left hand side mean the same as the double sum I have written?

Comment: When counting the number of terms, the left-hand side has $N(N-1)$ terms and the right-hand side has $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ terms. I think the original inequality doesn't hold in general case. Thus I suggest to change the righteous sigma $\sum\limits_{1\leq m<n}$ to be $\sum\limits_{m\leq N \\ m\neq n}$.

Comment: I have edited my question. As you pointed out the inequality does not hold in general. Maybe I can still prove the bound that I actually wanted to obtain in another way.

Comment: In edited problem, I checked when $N=2$. Then I got $\frac{17}{4}|a_1 a_2| \leq |a_1|^2 + 4|a_2|^2$. If $a_1 = 17$ and $a_2=8$, then this idequality doesn't hold.

Comment: The last inequality I have added is an asymptotic bound: it doesn't have to hold pointwise but only as $N\to\infty$. In other words it says that the left hand side is a "big oh" of the right hand side as $N$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$ put $b_n=|a_n|$ . Then $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers and we have to show that
$$\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{\substack{m\leq N\\ m\neq n}} b_mb_n\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\ll \sum_{n\leq N}n^2b_n^2
$$

$$\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{\substack{m\leq N\\ m\neq n}} b_mb_n\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\ll \sum_{n\leq N}n^2b_n^2$$
$$\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{\substack{m\leq N }} b_mb_n \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-2}\ll \sum_{n\leq N}(n^2+1)b_n^2 $$
$$\left( \sum_{n\leq N} b_nn^2\right)\left(\sum_{\substack{m\leq N }} b_mm^{-2}\right)\ll \sum_{n\leq N}(n^2+1)b_n^2 $$
Clearly, this inequality holds asymptotically iff $\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_mm^{-2}<\infty$.